# How to compare the sysdate and the date stored in CSV file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have a .csv file in which I have made a column where dates are given in a random manner. I want a script in which I want to compare the today date i.e., sysdate with the date present in CSV file.
And if today date matches with the date in CSV then it will `Write-Output` "true" else "false".

The date strings look like this:

```
 3/10/2016
 4/12/2016
 3/09/2016
```

I've tried this:

```
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).Date
Import-Csv 'C:\Downloads\date.csv' | Select-Object -Property *, @{n='Date';e={ [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'Date', 'MM-dd-yyyy') }} -Exclude 'Date' | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.'Date' -eq $CheckDate) { 
        write-Output "$true" 
    } else { 
        Write-output "$false" 
    } 
}
```

and this:

```
$data = Get-item "C:\Downloads\date.csv" 
$a = Get-Date -Format d 
if($a = $data) {
    write-output "Its working!!"
} else {
    write-output "Its not working!!"
}
```

Comment: Can you describe or show what have already tried? And please provide examples of the input csv.

Comment: What means "random manner"? Do you mean a "random" format?

Comment: random here means not in sequential manner like mm/dd/yyyy
3/10/2016
4/12/2016
3/09/2016....goes on

Comment: I tried this
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).Date
Import-Csv 'C:\Downloads\date.csv' |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='Date';e={
      [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'Date', 'MM-dd-yyyy')
    }} -Exclude 'Date' |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.'Date' -eq $CheckDate) {
 
write-Output "$true" 
}
else 
{
Write-output "$false"
}
}

Comment: Also I tried this

$data = Get-item "C:\Downloads\date.csv" 
$a= get-date -format d
if($a = $data)
{
    write-output "Its working!!"
}
else 
{
    write-output "Its not working!!"

}

Comment: @Amar Please don't post code in the comments section. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35935765/edit) link to update your question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the dates in the csv file look like:

```
 3/10/2016
 4/12/2016
 3/09/2016
```

But in your example, you attempt to parse the date using the format string `MM-dd-yyyy` - ie. expecting a month with leading zeros and `-` as the separator.

The correct date format for the samples you describe would be `%M/dd/yyyy`:

```
PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact('3/10/2016','%M/dd/yyyy',$null)

Thursday, March 10, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: The forward slashes need to be escaped (`\/`), otherwise they'll match whatever date separator is configured in the regional settings. With that said, for this particular date format parsing isn't required. You could simply cast it: `[datetime]'3/09/2016'`. Side note if you want to use `ParseExact()`: I'd recommend providing actual culture information for the third parameter (`[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` if you don't want a specific culture). I've seen the `ParseExact()` fail in some cases when `$null` was used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice..!

But I am not getting the desired output. I am unable to compare the dates.